# How do I calculate the accuracy?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, machine-learning, svm

I am in the final stage of SVM implementation in Java.

I have 10 datasets and among that `3 points` missclassified.

So what will be the equation to find accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accuracy of the algorithm is: `#samples_classified_correctly / #samples`.

If you have 10 samples, 7 out of them are correctly classified your accuracy is 0.7.

---

**However**, note that 10 samples is not statistically enough to estimate expected accuracy for samples that you don't know their classification (in the "real world").

Comment: where can i get a large file to chck the algorithm? i need a file which is nearly 1 GB with 1 and -1 classes. whr can i find tat?

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy is `(TP + TN) / #samples`, where:

- `TP` are the true positives (actual value is +1, and it is classified as +1)
- `TN` are the true negatives (actual value is -1, and it is classified as -1)

In classification tasks, beyond accuracy, many other measures are used to express the performance of a classifier, such as **precision**, **recall**, **ROC**, **area under the ROC** and **F1 score**.

You can find further information and equations here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision